# node js exec sql file

Tags: sql, node.js

Здравствуйте.
Не могу выполнить sql запрос из файла.
Есть два файла sql и js.

```js
var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;
var Request = require('tedious').Request;
var fs = require('fs');

var config = {
    userName: 'name',
    password: 'pass',
    server: 'srv',
    options: {database : 'bdname'}
  };

var connection = new Connection(config);
var sqlFile = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '\\sql\\query.sql', 'utf-8').toString();
console.log(sqlFile);

connection.on('connect', function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
      executeStatement();
      console.log('Connect database');
      }
    });
function executeStatement() {
  request = new Request(sqlFile, function(err, rowCount) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      //console.log(rowCount + ' rows'); //количество строк
    }
    connection.close();
    console.log('Disconnect database');
  });

  request.on('row', function(columns) {
    columns.forEach(function(column) {
      if (column.value === null) {
        console.log('NULL');
      } else {
        console.log(column.value);
      }
    });
  });

  connection.execSql(request);
}
```

```
use mao2

--select код_поиска from [зоны ответственности]
select [name] from [Domains]
```

В таком виде запрос выполняет, но если раскомментировать первую строку, а вторую наоборот, то он ругается "Incorrect syntax near '�'". Понимаю, что проблема с кодировкой файла, на разобраться не могу. Спасибо.

Comment: Пробовали менять кодировку sql файла? На utf8 без BOM например

Comment: Как все просто оказалось. Спасибо, выручили.